# Проблема с сохранением в контроллере отмеченных checkbox Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

На одной вьюхе выбираются chechbox и по нажатию кнопки происходит переход на новую вьюху с полями для заполнения и после нажатия кнопки добавить, должны использоваться поля из формы и отмеченные checkboxs.

Проблема в следующем когда  я передаю  отмеченные checkbox в контролер 2 вьюхи все проходит отлично, но после того как заполнить поля и  нажимаю кнопку добавить функция в контроллере опять вызывается и Request $request очищается и массив отмеченных chechbox пропадает. Вопрос как сохранить массив отмеченные checkbox в контроллере при 2 вызове(после нажатия кнопки добавить ) ? Или как передать массив отмеченные checkbox через путь в роуте, а то как переменные передавать знаю а вот массив что то не встречал ?

Извиняюсь за кривое объяснение, может кто что подскажет.
Есть варианты конечно в бд положить массив отмеченных чекбоксов, а потом прочитать, но может у кого то ещё идеи есть

Comment: После сабмита первой вьюхи обработайте полученные значения, приведите их в строку и засуньте в скрытый инпут второй вьюхи, как вариант. Я правильно понял, что у Вас одна и та же форма сабмитится дважды?

Comment: @DaemonHK про скрытый импут думал, но массив checkbox  может содержать до 300 значений, причем там 2 поля в это айдишники групп и название групп, поэтому очень геморно в строчку будет запихивать, а потом из строчки потом разделять обратно

Comment: @DaemonHK нет,  сабмится  1 раз на каждой вьюхе, на одной вьюхе выбрал checkbox по нажатию кнопки перешел на новую вьюху с полями, а массив отмеченных checkbox попал в контроллер, потом заполнил поля и нажимаю добавить, опять вызывается контроллер второй вьюхе но там массив Request содержит уже значение полей формы а  массива отмеченных checkbox из первой вьюхе  уже нет

Comment: Я возможно криво объясняю, или вопрос сильно тупой, а то народ смотрит и что то ни у кого идей нет

Comment: Форма регистрации, опросник? Создайте запись в БД и обновляйте ее по мере прохождения по вьюхам. Как вариант.

Comment: @DaemonHK Нет, типо пользователь выбирает места куда отправлять в checkbox название места и айдишник, а потом в формах заполняет куча полей, типо в начале куда отправлять а потом что отправлять.

Comment: @DaemonHK ну бд наверно не оптимально, потому что сотни пользователь будет,  и десятки раз в день подгружать эти места, по анологии и в файл можно записывать, хотя про бд интересная идея можно попробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали идеальное решение, хранить все в сессии с помощью драйвера ссессий database. Всем спасибо за помощь.